# How can I use the bing api from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, bing, bing-api

I am working in a rails 5 app and I would like to use the bing api from my app. I can't find a gem for Bing, so I added Savon gem to use soap. I don't know how should I use the savon and soap. For example, I want to get this information:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bing-ads-campaign-management-getcampaignsbyaccountid.aspx#request_soap

Is there an example using the Bing API?

Answer (score 0):

What about starting from the following gems:

- https://github.com/jonahb/bing-search
- https://github.com/rcullito/searchbing

You could fork them or inspire yourself to write "fresh" code!